# Deny upload of non-image file types, allow only specific .php files in uploads dir

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

I'm not very good when it comes to .htaccess rules so I'm seeking your help.

I'm trying to find a set of rules that would enhance the security of my PHP app in the following manners:

1. Deny upload of all file types except for images [jpg, png, gif] and docs [pdf, doc, docx]
2. Deny access to all [php, php3] files except for index.php, image.php in folder /uploads and all sub folders

PS: My goal is to deny the upload and direct access to malicious uploaders even if they find away to bypass my uploads handler. The reason I'm seeking a solution with .htaccess is because rewriting the code would be very time consuming as the app has been deployed on a number of websites.

Comment: mod_rewrite can not look at a request’s body, so you can’t check for uploaded files.

Comment: Can it not deny access to the creation of them?

Comment: The server creates the file automatically on upload. Just check the file name extension with PHP before moving it with `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: The reason I'm seeking a solution with .htaccess is because rewriting the code would be very time consuming as the app has been deployed on a number of websites.

Comment: Then you can stop searching as there is no solution with mod_rewrite.

Comment: _“because rewriting the code would be very time consuming as the app has been deployed on a number of websites”_ – well that happens when you deploy stuff without considering security implications properly beforehand.

Comment: If that was the case there would never be any vulnerabilities, backdoors or security issues. However, in the real world, problems occur and patches are part of the software/code improvement.